# VHDL: bound check error when adding two numbers

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Why does this VHDL code cause a bounds check failure?  My result signal is 1 bit wider than the widest number being added... thus it shouldn't overflow...  Am i missing something?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity testbench is
end entity;

architecture sim of testbench is
    constant dw       :natural                 := 8;
    signal   arg1     :unsigned(dw-1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(4, dw);       
    signal   result   :unsigned(dw+0 downto 0);
begin
    result <= arg1 + '1';
end architecture;
```

> C:> ghdl -a --std=08 --ieee=synopsys --work=work testbench.vhd
>
> C:> ghdl --elab-run --std=08 --ieee=synopsys testbench
>   --ieee-asserts=disable
>
> ghdl.exe:error: bound check failure at testbench.vhd:13   from:
>   process work.testbench(sim).P0 at testbench.vhd:13
>
> ghdl.exe:error: simulation failed

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. Note the bounds of arg1 is unsigned(dw-1 downto 0) which will define the length of the result (the greater of either operand for --std=08 for -2008 compatibility numeric_std."+" will convert the right operand to a std_ulogic_vector with a length of the left operand). The result length will match the left operand length but you've specified a longer length for result unsigned(dw+0 downto 0) which will produce a bound check error during run time - there isn't a matching element on the right hand side for every element on the left hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

The vector operand of the addition should have the same length as the target of the assignment. Extend if needed:

```
result <= ('0' & arg1) + '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a note to @renaud's answer. VHDL is strongly typed language, That is every signal on the both sides of an operator should have exact matching types and sizes.
 Hence care must be taken in ensuring that the types of all signals you have used in the expression is of same size and type.
 In your code since you have allocated a extra bit for overflow, you should also change the size of the input signal.
 This is not a problem in verilog though, It takes care of the mismatch by padding of the bits.
 Though Frustrating, VHDL is quite helpful in clearing out many bugs before simulation.

Comment: **That is every signal on the both sides of an operator should have exact matching types and sizes.**  This isn't true. For example IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators para 4 "... Two composite values of the same type are equal if and only if for each element of the left operand there is a *matching element* of the right operand and vice versa, and the values of matching elements are equal, as given by the predefined equality operator for the element type. In particular, two null arrays of the same type are always equal. ...".

Comment: There's also arithmetic operators, concatenation in particular or otherwise along with multiplying operators  in packages numeric_std and numeric_bit as more examples. There's also the miscellaneous exponentiating operator.